# What good patterns for a web framework are out there?

Tags: design-patterns, frameworks

What are design patterns that would be useful for a web framework **besides MVC**, the Rails-induced frenzy? Not saying it's a bad thing, but it is now practically ubiquitous in web frameworks.

Ideally the pattern should make easier:

- **Separation of concerns**
- Modularity / reusability of code
- Unit testing

What patterns fit the bill? Are there example of frameworks out that follow it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC is *not* a Rails-induced frenzy.  It goes back to Smalltalk.  You can check out the history in the GoF book as well, which pre-dates Rails.

I don't know about patterns beyond the GoF book, but I'd say that general ideas of layering (e.g., separate web, service, and persistence tiers) and decomposition apply regardless.

Comment: I know MVC predates Rails; but it wasn't until Rails that it became ubiquitous in web frameworks.

Comment: Not true.  It was there in Struts 1.

Comment: JSF is component-version of Struts.  Seam is the combination of Hibernate and Struts.  Spring is an extension of Model-2 MVC that improves on the deficiencies of Struts.  All descended from Craig Walls' original idea.  All predate Rails by quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) web framework follows what its creators call [View First](http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php?title=Lift_View_First).

Where this differs from MVC is that control is handled first by the view, not by a controller. The view may call logic in several *snippets* (the closest to an analogue of controllers).

I see this as an inversion of RESTful design, where URLs are mapped to resources, and views are a way of displaying these resources. In View First, URLs map to views, which may pull out and display any arbitrary collection of resources.

The reasoning behind this is that often, a page on a web site or application needs to display much more than simply the resource that was requested: it might have a list of recent blog comments, a 'shout box', et cetera. Other frameworks handle this by having secondary mechanisms for showing content and handling input (such as Django's template inclusion tags and middleware), and leaving the controller* to handle the primary resource that the page is displaying.

(* It's tricky to involve Django in discussions like this because essentially it is MVC, although for subtle reasons its creators use the terms Model-View-Template. Here, though, I will call Django's *view* a *controller*.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter)?

It's a well-known alternative to MVC, and is covered in many of the "well-known" pattern books.

You can read [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html) that Martin Fowler has actually split the MVP into two patterns.

Here is one [MVP framework for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/mvp-php/).

And here is [one for .NET](http://aspnetmvp.codeplex.com/).

It's worth noting that the .NET guys responsible for MVC were also influenced by django, not just rails.

Answer (score 1):

Naked Objects

http://www.nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml

I should clarify that this uses MVC but in a very different way

Answer (score 0):

Subject Observer pattern

Factory Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Although MVVM (or DM-V-VM) was already mentioned, there is a good series about it on the [MSDN network](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/tags/dm_2d00_v_2d00_vm/) (although it mainly concerns WPF). If you're looking for another DM-V-VM example,  I happen to have written a [PHP framework](http://code.google.com/p/mgframework/) largely following the pattern.

Furthermore, I believe there are quite a lot of different interpretations of MVC in web application development. Just compare the ideas (regarding MVC) behind [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) for instance. I haven't used RoR, but I would look further than just RoR to get a good view on MVC (again, in web app dev ;).